# Update cell using UI menu (Googe Sheets Scripts)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to update a cells value dependent on on another cell in the same row. This is mean't to be done by the setRankID function, but no matter what I've tried it just spits out errors.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  ui.createMenu('Daniagaming EMS Tools')
    .addItem('Opdater RID\'s', 'setRankID')
    .addToUi();
}

function setRankID() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      range = ss.range,
      columnNumberToWatch = 1; // A = 1, B = 2 etc.

  if(sheet.getName() === "Ark1" && range.columnStart === columnNumberToWatch) {
    if(ss.value === "Commisioner") {
      sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 2).setValue("1");
    }
  }
}
```

What I wan't it to do is when using the function through the UI, to check cells in column A and update the value of column B dependent on column A's value.

Like if column A has the value "Test1" then column B should be set to the value "Toast".

Comment: There is no range or columnStart or value methods in Spreadsheet.  Check the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of what I think you were asking for.  It's hard to tell because your setRankID function has a lot errors.

```
function simpleExample()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('deleteDupes');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rngA[i][0]=='Test1')
    {
      sht.getRange(i+1,2).setValue('Toast');
    }
    else
    if(rngA[i][0])
    {
      sht.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(rngA[i][0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what my spreadsheet looks like before running the function:

[image]

Here's what it looks like after:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear in my description of the problem I had.